# Can a Chrome extension change its large (new tab page) icon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, tabs, icons

My question is along the same lines as this: [Change the Chrome extension icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921685/change-the-chrome-extension-icon)

But I'm wondering instead about the large icon of the extension on a new tab page. Can it change itself based on data? All I have in mind is a simple countdown-calendar (as in, the whole point of the extension is to be a big ol' number on your new tab page), so the actual code wouldn't have to be very long, if icon-changing is possible. (It wouldn't even need to sync or connect to the Internet for any reason.)

My strong hunch is no, because I've never seen an extension do so, and I would expect that if it could, my Chrome's Gmail button would probably display the number of new messages or something. But I figured it didn't hurt to ask.

PS: I've never created a Chrome extension, I just had that idea for one just now. Anyone reading this can feel free to do it themselves, but otherwise I'll make it when I get the time, as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [apps](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) (not [extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html)) can have an icon on the New Tab page (NTP).

This icon have to be declared via the [`icons` property in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/icons.html), and cannot dynamically be updated.

I can imagine two ways to get a dynamic icon on the options page:

- Create an extension that replaces the New Tab page. Have a look at the docs for [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override.html).
- Create an extension that uses the [`chrome.management`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html) API to enable/disable apps. This method might work for your personal setup, but it requires a new App for each icon. This feels a bit hacky, but hey, it might work.

Comment: "Dynamic"! That's the word I'd been looking for. And I hadn't realized the app-extension distinction (I considered apps to be a subset of extensions, maybe I was wrong).

Anyway, It looks like an override page is one of the simplest possible extensions to do. I'll try that, and the effect might be even stronge than I had in mind -- until my countdown is done and my event's occurred (and I disable the extension), my new tab page will be starkly different, hence reminding me further.

Comment: FYI, There's another kind of "app", called "[Packaged Apps](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/apps.html)".